# Discord.net: voiceChannel.ConnectAsync(true, false, true) returns null

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

```
 var voiceChannel = (command.User as IGuildUser).VoiceChannel != null
     ? (command.User as IGuildUser).VoiceChannel
     : null;

 if (voiceChannel != null)
 {
     var audioClient = await voiceChannel.ConnectAsync(true, false, false);
 }
```

if the 'external' parameter of the ConnectAsync method is false
`ConnectAsync(true, false, FALSE)`
the bot connects to the voice channel and gives an error:
Gateway A SlashCommandExecuted handler is blocking the gateway task.
It stays in the voice channel for a few more seconds and exits with the following error:

> Gateway A SlashCommandExecuted handler has thrown an unhandled
> exception....: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
> at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId,
> Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)    at
> Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId,
> Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)    at
> Program.HandlePlayCommand(SocketSlashCommand command) in
> C:\Users\ol1Hu\Workbench\Files\code\code\c#\TestDSBot\Program.cs:line
> 210    at Program.SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command) in
> C:\Users\ol1Hu
> Desktop\Files\code\code\code\c#\TestDSBot\Program.cs:line 136    at
> Discord.EventExtensions.InvokeAsync[T](AsyncEvent`1 eventHandler, T arg)    at Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.TimeoutWrap(String name, Func`1 action)

If the 'external' parameter of the ConnectAsync method is true
`ConnectAsync(true, false, TRUE)`
the ConnectAsync method simply returns null, but the bot connects to the voice channel without any errors.

The original goal was to create a music bot. The code is made almost exactly according to [discord.net documentation](https://discordnet.dev/guides/voice/sending-voice.html).

```
private async Task HandlePlayCommand(SocketSlashCommand command)
{
    var voiceChannel = (command.User as IGuildUser).VoiceChannel != null
        ? (command.User as IGuildUser).VoiceChannel
        : null;

    if (voiceChannel != null)
    {
        await command.RespondAsync(embed: new EmbedBuilder { Description = "Please wait..." }.Build(), ephemeral: true);
        var audioClient = await voiceChannel.ConnectAsync(true, false, false);
        try
        {
            using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream(@"path to file"))
            using (var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
            using (var discord = audioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
            {
                try
                {
                    await output.CopyToAsync(discord);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally { await discord.FlushAsync(); }
            }
            await command.RespondAsync(embed: new EmbedBuilder { Description = "Ready!" }.Build(), ephemeral: true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
        await command.RespondAsync(embed: new EmbedBuilder { Description = "You must be in the voice channel!" }.Build(), ephemeral: true);
}

private Process CreateStream(string path)
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "ffmpeg",
        Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -i \"{path}\" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    });
}
```